# Tailwind UI Tree View, Table Component in React.js

Tags: reactjs

Please refer to attached screenshots.

I am after a clean. crisp Tailwind based UI - 2 deliverables :

- Tree
- Table Display

Fitting in with tailwind UI, compatible with current design - see dark screenshot. Mobile first design to support resizing screens for different devices.

Tree:
Flexible to have as many levels as the data provided to the component. For example, if the data has 3 levels, there will be 3 levels in the tree. If there are 5, then the tree will have 5 levels.

If you click a + button on the table, it needs to load child records (async)

Table:
A clean table display that is crisp and modern. Resizable columns, easy to scroll through many rows, with navigation by page, first, last, etc.

Creativity and initiative are welcome.
https://snipboard.io/pq3Zx0.jpg

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? And do you have code to share? If so please add it to the question, if not give it a shot yourself and ask another question when you run into an issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.